# Fetching the matched string from the text using findstr

Tags: regex, windows

I have a text in some file like

```
<Variable name="URL"  value="http://url:port"/>
```

I want the url in the value tag( `http://url:port` ).

The command and regex I'm using are

```
FindStr /R /C:"\"URL\" *value=*\"*\"" <filename>
```

The above regex matches the line in the file but fails to extract that url string

any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findstr will not capture any values for you. If you can download tools, you can try [gawk for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm)

```
C:\test>gawk "/value/{ gsub(/.*value=\042|\042.*/,\"\");print }" file
http://url:port
```

If not, you can use vbscript

```
strFile= WScript.Arguments(0)
Set objFS = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set objFile = objFS.OpenTextFile(strFile)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strLine=objFile.ReadLine    
    If InStr(strLine,"value=") > 0 Then
        s=Split(strLine,"value=")       
        s1=Replace(s(1),"/>","")
        WScript.Echo s1
    End If
Loop
```

usage:

```
C:\test>cscript //nologo test.vbs file
"http://url:port"
```